# How do i use square root function in UDF in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

why JS sqrt() function is not working?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION sqt(x int64)
RETURNS int64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return sqrt(x);
""";

with table1 as(
select 25 as x union all 
select 100 as x union all 
select 625 as x 
)

select x,sqt(x)square_root from table1
```

Error: ReferenceError: sqrt is not defined at sqt(INT64) line 2, columns 2-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript function is `Math.sqrt`. Try this instead:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION sqt(x int64)
RETURNS int64
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Math.sqrt(x);
""";

with table1 as(
select 25 as x union all 
select 100 as x union all 
select 625 as x 
)

select x,sqt(x)square_root from table1
```

Note that `INT64` is not an officially supported type for JavaScript UDFs (since there is no equivalent JavaScript type). It's a good idea to use `FLOAT64` instead.